# Where can I use ---fix in project?

Tags: typescript, flutter

Im getting 33 errors but I can fix with--fix . My question is where I pass this command?Hope anyone can help

```
✖ 35 problems (35 errors, 0 warnings)
  33 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint --ext .js,.ts .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

This is my file whee the errors located.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();

export const onConversationCreated = functions.firestore.
document("Conversations/{conversationID}").onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    let data = snapshot.data();
    let conversationID = context.params.conversationID;
    if (data) {
        let members = data.members;
        for (let index = 0; index < members.length; index++) {
            let uid = members[index];
            let remainingUserIDs = members.filter((u:string) => u !== uid);
            remainingUserIDs.forEach((m:string) => {
                return admin.firestore().collection("meinprofilsettings").doc(m).get().then((_doc) => {
                    let userData = _doc.data();
                    if (userData) {
                        return admin.firestore().collection("meinprofilsettings").doc(uid).collection("Conversations").doc(m).create({
                            "conversationID": conversationID,
                            "url": userData.url,
                            "name": userData.username,
                            "unseenCount": 0,
                        });
                    }
                    return null;
                }).catch(() => { return null; });
            });
        }
    }
    return null;
});
```

and maybe anyone knows what's the 2 other errors meaning?

Im getting this errors when im running npm run lint -- --fix

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/name/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/name/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/name/.npm/_logs/2021-03-25T12_43_38_604Z-debug.log
```

Heres the first picture[image]
And the other.

[image]

Comment: What are the other errors?

Comment: I mean these to errors thats not fixable with --fix command

Comment: Yeh, after fixing the auto-fixable errors, please paste those errors here

Comment: Im getting no error anymore but at my new function there's seems to be something wrong . Maybe you can check my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66807510/why-my-function-dont-getting-uploaded-in-to-firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
npm run lint -- --fix
```

Comment: Should I pass this inside the terminal ?

Comment: Yes, just like you run your `node app.js` or how you run your script.

Comment: I get error when im trying to use this please check my latest post update

Comment: In which directory, the first command was run and where are running the command with `--fix`

Comment: And I just wanna update my script to firebase inside my project as a function with this command firebase deploy --only functions

Comment: I see that NPM cannot find package.json, can you spost structure of the files? package.json should be in same directory as you running the script @usinguser

Comment: please check update hope this was what you mean if not please say what else

Comment: I See I already enter the correct picture ? Isnt there package json?

Comment: @usinguser Go to the project root and run- `cd functions && npm run lint -- --fix`

Comment: @usinguser I would just move the index.ts to parent folder (same where the package.json is) and you are good to go, you can then create folder with your other stuff.

Comment: I think that was it but your first answer was better the without cd  functions&&. I trying it first I have to enter my bill account without that it will not working. @Shivam Singla